Firebase throwing error on FirebaseAuth initialization
FirebaseAuth always throws an error whenever I initialize final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;.
The error is Null check operator used on a null value.
So I have to use it in a function such as the one below before it works.
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collectionPath") .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).snapshots();
I don't want to write that long code everytime.
What can I do to resolve this?

You should use an auth state listener to know when the user is signed in, then update your UI accordingly.  currentUser is going to be null until then (especially when the app is first launched), and it's a bad idea to blindly assume that it's not null.

In the line of the code
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

You are using ! operator which tells the code that uid will never be null.
In your case, it seems currentUser is null, because the Authentication was not successful. So you need to check like this
if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null){
 FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
}

or
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid ?? '' // if uid is String 

to understand more about Null Safety best to check Dart documentation
